# RSS Reader creating custom browser

Tags: php, ajax, browser, web, rss

I am currently working on an rss reader (in php) and was wondering if anyone had any tips on how to make a custom browser (i.e. have the link open up within the reader itself rather than take you to a new webpage.) I have never done this and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your RSS Reader does already run in the browser right?

Then you could use an

```
iframe
```

to display other websites inside your reader without the need for a new tab or something. More about iframes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe